# ITemplate ID needs to be unique

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am working on a project where i need to create a Datagrid TemplateColumn via the codebehind which will contain an ImageButton; i have found what i required on [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7227/DataGrid-Template-Columns-creation-in-Runtime-usin), but the only issue i have is when i run the code at run-time i get the following exception when trying to find the Control via the ItemDataBound method of the DataGrid

> Multiple controls with the same ID 'uxPlusMinusImageButton' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs.

This is my code

DataGridPopulateMethod

```
private void PopulateDataGrid()
{
    TemplateColumn plusMinusContractImage = new TemplateColumn();
    plusMinusContractImage.ItemTemplate = new PlusMinusColumn("uxPlusMinusImageButton");

uxSummaryInfoDataGrid.ItemDataBound += new DataGridItemEventHandler(uxSummaryInfoDataGrid_ItemDataBound);
uxSummaryInfoDataGrid.DataSource = contracts;
uxSummaryInfoDataGrid.Columns.Add(new BoundColumn() { HeaderText = "ID", DataField = "ColumnID", Visible = false });
uxSummaryInfoDataGrid.Columns.Add(plusMinusContractImage);
uxSummaryInfoDataGrid.Columns.Add(new BoundColumn() { HeaderText = "Title 1", DataField = "Column1" });
uxSummaryInfoDataGrid.Columns.Add(new BoundColumn() { HeaderText = "Title 2", DataField = "Column2" });
uxSummaryInfoDataGrid.DataBind();
```

DataGridOnItemDataBoundMethod

```
private void uxSummaryInfoDataGridItemDataBound(DataGrid summaryDataGrid, DataGridItem item)
{
    if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        SummaryInformation summaryInfo = (SummaryInformation)item.DataItem;
        ImageButton plusMinusImageButton = (ImageButton)item.Cells[1].FindControl("uxPlusMinusImageButton");
        plusMinusImageButton.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(PlusMinusImageButton_Click);
```

ImageButton Click

```
protected void PlusMinusImageButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
  PopulateDataGrid();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue, i was getting this error as i wasn't clearing the original dynamic datagrid columns out so it was making the controls with the same name.